# SMTP Data Error when using sendgrid in django

Tags: django, email, smtp, sendgrid

I am encountering the following error when I try to send emails from my django app despite having setup sendgrid correctly

[image]

here is my configuration in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MY_API_KEY'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

could django be having a from email that it is set to by default that needs to be overridden?

Comment: The error text contains a URL which should point you towards the issue, I believe there is some value that must be set in the sendgrid side. As an aside- I highly recommend using [django-anymail](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail) which has support for sendgrid (among others).

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

From [the docs](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity):

> To ensure our customers maintain the best possible sender reputations and to uphold legitimate sending behavior, we require customers to verify their Sender Identities. A Sender Identity represents your “From” email address—the address your recipients will see as the sender of your emails.

In order to verify a sender identity you can either set up [single sender verification](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) or [domain authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication).

Single sender verification is quicker, but only allows you to send from a single email address. This is useful for testing. Domain authentication requires access to DNS records to set up, but will allow you to send from any email address on a domain as well as improve overall deliverability and reputation.

Once you have verified your sender identity you can set the default from email address in your application with the [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL). On a per-email basis, you can also use the [`from_email` argument when using `send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#send-mail).